# How to align content in Woocommerce checkout?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to ask how to align the "Update cart" button and the total amount to the right side and make the grey line full-length. I tried to use some CSS, but it didn't work for me, it always broke the checkout page even more. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

https://www.jgaparty.com/en/checkout/

Comment: Add a new class to your cart button class="button button-cart", then add .button-cart { margin-left: xx } in your css style...

Comment: Also, I think your items (update cart button, total) are in the same div. Change the width of this div to 100%;

Comment: It's not actually possible without the knowledge of changing your cart's PHP file or using JS. Recommended way is to edit PHP file cart which you can find in the woocommerce plugin `/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php`. Copy that to in your theme and make changes in it, it will replace the default one which plugin is using.

If you can provide content of that file, that'd be helpful

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/11987538)